# Saving Oracle SQL Developer script as a TEXT file (as in ascii... as in Notepad...)

Tags: text, plsql, ascii

New to Oracle...

I have a bunch of SQL scripts from SQL Server that I want to edit into Oracle.  I load these notepad-capable ASCII text files (ex: myscript.sql) into SQL Developer.  When I open it, SQL Developer adds an extra line break between every line I had in the ascii text file.  Annoying, but I can deal with that.  I soldier on.  I edit and change syntax.  I run it.  It works.  I save.  I'm happy so far.  Feeling good.

But...

Now when I try to open myscript.sql in Notepad, line breaks are gone... there is a blank between every character in a word... it's a mess.

What the heck happened?  And how do I make it stop?  I know I'm old school, but I like to edit the format of my scripts myself... I want them in ascii text so that I can use a bulk file editor to change things...

I have googled this for a couple hours and have found countless pages regarding saving the OUTPUT of a script as text, but nothing about saving a SQL Developer script as plain text.

Comment: Please add the script.

Comment: Start with this from Notepad:

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of UNIX vs Windows/DOS line ending differences.

I would recommend using a better editor than Notepad.  A modern code editing program will automatically handle the conversion and display.

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html

Comment: Interesting... ASCII text was used by Fred Flintstone at Slate Rock and Gravel...  

I downloaded Notepad++ .  OPened one of my SQL Developer-mangled scripts and see tons of NUL's.  I'll try to attach a screen shot.  

Shouldn't be this hard :(

Comment: More baffling...

A couple of the scripts I have edited end up in this odd state - nulls between every character... etc.  Others are just fine.  I opened in SQL Developer... edited...saved... and Notepad is perfectly happy with them.

Still tinkering... must... under....   stand...

Comment: nulls between every character suggest some sort of unicode encoding.

Answer (score 0):

So I still don't know how a couple of my scripts got so mangled up, because I can't recreate the issue.  Other scripts are editing and saving just fine.

But I did figure out how to fix the couple scripts that did get hosed up.

I loaded Notepad++ for Windows.  I opened the offending script, which shows a bunch of [NUL] all over the place.  I was able to use the Searce/Replace function in 'extended mode' to search for \x00 (aka null) and replace it with nothing.

Next was the annoyance with line breaks (new line) versus "carriage return plus new line".  I was able to use extended search and replace to replace \n with \r\n .

This now got me a file that I could edit in 'regular' notepad.  I still don't know where the extra line breaks came into play, but I was able to spin through the file and remove the extra blank lines.

So all is well with the universe again.  I got my couple of mangled scripts back in order, and others seem to behave properly now.

Thanks to all for the help.  This site has been invaluable to me.